# Push to heroku fails

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, git, heroku

I am following this tutorial https://www.codementor.io/jamesezechukwu/how-to-deploy-django-app-on-heroku-dtsee04d4 for deploying my Django app to heroku. This is my first Django app:

Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

I'm currently running python 3.7.0. this is set in my runtime.txt file:
`python-3.7.0`

stack trace:

```
Enumerating objects: 11614, done.
Counting objects: 100% (11614/11614), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (8294/8294), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11614/11614), 42.09 MiB | 3.12 MiB/s, done.
Total 11614 (delta 2534), reused 8489 (delta 2166)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.7.3
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.7.0
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip



remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-r7xse4_1/django-dbbackup/setup.py", line 59, in <module>
remote:                install_requires=get_requirements(),
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-r7xse4_1/django-dbbackup/setup.py", line 45, in get_requirements
remote:                import pysftp  # @UnusedImport
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysftp.py", line 10, in <module>
remote:                import paramiko
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
remote:                from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 61, in <module>
remote:                from paramiko.sftp_client import SFTPClient
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 41, in <module>
remote:                from paramiko.sftp_file import SFTPFile
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_file.py", line 66
remote:                self._close(async=True)
remote:                                ^
remote:            SyntaxError: invalid syntax
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-r7xse4_1/django-dbbackup/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-3pz1o34a-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-r7xse4_1/django-dbbackup/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to {my_app}.
remote: 


 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/{my_app.git}'
```

the requirements txt file:

```
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astroid==1.4.9
bcrypt==3.1.4
boto==2.34.0
boto3==1.9.38
botocore==1.12.104
cffi==1.11.5
coverage==4.5.1
cryptography==2.3.1
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==2.2.4
django-dbbackup==2.0.4
django-filter==0.8
django-jsonfield==0.9.13
django-markdown-deux==1.0.5
django-oauth-plus==2.2.8
django-oauth2-provider==0.2.6.1
django-sslify==0.2.5
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
djangorestframework==2.4.4
djangorestframework-oauth==1.0.1
docutils==0.14
ecdsa==0.13
eventlog==0.11.0
gunicorn==19.1.1
httplib2==0.9
idna==2.7
isort==4.3.9
jmespath==0.9.4
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
Markdown==2.5.2
markdown2==2.3.0
mccabe==0.6.1
mock==2.0.0
newrelic==2.44.0.36
numpy==1.17.0
oauth2==1.9.0.post1
pandas==0.25.0
paramiko==1.15.2
pbr==5.1.2
pgeocode==0.1.1
psycopg2==2.7.5
py-mini-racer==0.1.15
pyasn1==0.4.4
pycparser==2.18
pycrypto==2.6.1
pylint==1.6.5
PyNaCl==1.2.1
pysftp==0.2.8
pystache==0.5.4
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2018.4
requests==2.2.1
requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
rsa==3.4.2
s3transfer==0.1.13
shortuuid==0.4.0
six==1.8.0
South==0.8.4
sqlparse==0.3.0
sqreen==1.13.3
static==1.1.1
static3==0.5.1
ua-parser==0.8.0
urllib3==1.24.1
user-agents==1.1.0
wh==1.2.0
whitenoise==1.0.6
wrapt==1.11.1
xkcdpass==1.2.5
```

is there something I've missed? im assuming its a python 3 issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of paramiko (1.15.2) isn't compatible with python 3.7. Use a newer version. It uses the `async` keyword which is reserved as argument in a function call.

If you look at the latest version, you'll see that [this particular line](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/sftp_file.py#L76) of code is now using `async_`.

You should always use the same version of python on your local machine as on production to spot these errors earlier.

I also suggest you look at some of the other dependencies, your version of `gunicorn` is also more than 5 years old, it contains security vulnerabilities, so may some other (old) packages you're using.

Finally, use `pip freeze` to compare what's installed in your local virtualenv compared to `requirements.txt`. And make sure they are the same!

Comment: thank you for the response, can I upgrade the requirements.txt file to a new version to fix the issue?

Comment: yes. but first make sure you change your virtualenv locally to also use python 3.7 and do the upgrade there as well, the version of paramiko you're using in your requirements is 5(!) years old so upgrading to the latest version might bring some unexpected other issues.

Comment: running 'python3 --version' shows my vent is running 3.7.0. I've upgrade paramiko and the corresponding issues raised (thankfully only 2 other requirements needed upgrading!), but still getting the same stack trace error

Comment: that's not possible, the latest version 2.6.0 uses `async_` so it can't raise the same error if you set the version correctly in your requirements file.

Comment: when in my virtual environment I run the command -> python --version. which returns Python 3.7.0

Comment: ok, then probably locally you were running a different version of paramiko than specified in your requirements file. Heroku just uses the requirements file to install all the packages, but locally if you just do `pip install paramiko` at some stage, it could be a different version than the one in your requirements.

Comment: that makes sense! however, I've updated paramiko and its now 2.6.0 but im still getting the exact same error - >           File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_file.py", line 66
remote:                self._close(async=True)

Comment: I've re-installed the requirements.txt but nothing. is there any other steps I need before running -> git push heroku master?

Comment: run git commit? sorry if that's obvious, can't think of anything else why heroku wouldn't see the change. I mean, check in your remote repository (where your git push) that requirements.txt contains the correct line for paramiko

Comment: ah it was the request requirement needed upgraded! Thank you so much!